# Creating a new column from existing column in the data frame based on the criteria

Tags: python

Create a new column based on the below criteria. Data Type for column A is String

If there exists a text in column A string.  Create column B which contains only the string. 
eg:  Column A: This product is used for pipefitter
     Desired: if column A contains pipefitter
     Column B = pipefitter

```
"""df["New_text"] = []
def update_text(selected_text):
    for text in df['Activity Name']:
        if selected_text in text:
            df['New_text'] = df['New_text'].append('text')"""
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: Append returns none, you don't need to assign it back

Comment: I am very new can you tell me how I can assign it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understand correctly. You have a column `Activity Name` in your dataframe and you want to write a method which would each time print a subset of a dataframe which has a particular keyword.

If my understanding is right then.

```
def update_text(df, selected_text):
    return df[df["Activity Name"].str.contains(selected_text)]
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks, Nithin

Comment: Your answer works just fine. But can I assign it a new data frame? something   dfnew == df[df["Activity Name"].str.contains(selected_text)]

Comment: `==` will compare the two items. you can try df_new = df[df["Activity Name"].str.contains(selected_text)].copy()